# Best way to include a big file that can't be stored on GitHub in a python package

Tags: python, file, download, package

When I make a python package, I often include some non-python files such as the requirements.txt, configuration files, documentations or small data files. Using the following script, it is easy for any user to pip install the package directly from github:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os 
current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
version = '0.0.0.0.0.0' # year.month.day.hour.minute.second
with open(os.path.join(current_folder,'VERSION')) as version_file:
    version = version_file.read().strip()

setup(name='package_name',
      version=version,
      description='My Little Python Package',
      url='https://github.com/github_user_name/package_name',
      author='Me',
      author_email='me@email.com',
      license='MIT',
      include_package_data=True,
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['docs', 'tests']),
      package_data={'': ['package_name/resources/*', 'package_name/conf.yml']},
      install_requires=[
          'numpy',
          'scipy',
          'PyMySQL',
          'PyYAML'
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Then, if I do: `pip install git+https://github.com/github_user_name/package_name`, the package is installed with the necessary files. Sadly, it is not possible to upload files that are more than 50 Mb on GitHub. Let say I want to provide a 1 Gb file with the package (example: a dataset of 1 million small texts). What is the best practice to do so ? Some suggestions:

1. Give an additional link on the GitHub's readme as a prerequisites.
2. Add a line in the setup.py file that downloads the data (ideally it stores the data in the package directory, not sure if possible).
3. Create an explicit script in the package that fetches the data.
4. Other ?

The only example I know is [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/data.html), which uses the 3rd otpion.

Answer (score 1):

You should look Into [Git Large file storage](https://git-lfs.github.com). It will create pointers of the large files to another server so you can exceed the 50 MB size limit.

From their **Getting Started** guide:

```
# This part is only done once
git lfs install
git lfs track "*.psd" # Or your file extension
git add .gitattributes

# Normal workflow begins
git add file.psd
git commit -m "Add design file"
git push origin master
```

Comment: Great, I did not realize it was specifically working with GitHub. Still I would like to find a pythonic way of doing this :-)